# RESET(bar) Pin of ATmega16

Tags: avr, atmega, reset

The datasheet says that an External Reset is generated by a low level on the RESET pin. And after reset all my conditions and values will be set to initial values.
I have connected the Reset(bar) pin to ground via a switch. After running the code for some time, I press the switch and give ground to Reset. But, nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me why this occured ?? Do I have to write a code?

Comment: Why do you believe that "nothing" happens?

Comment: I had a display which displays the value of variables.

Comment: Check initial pin state, RESET is generated on falling edge, so if your pin is in LOW state, and you set them again to LOW, nothing happen ofcourse.

Comment: nRESET only resets the MCU and registers, not the SRAM or external peripherals.

Comment: If it doesn't resets the data in RAM, then how can I write a code to say that 
if(RESET)
     Reset all variables

Comment: @yash: You do not "write **a** code" (singular reference to a code in a cryptography / coding theory sense). You just "write [source] code".

Comment: Are you writing the code in C or assembler?

Comment: When not connected to ground, is the pin floating, or pulled high?  It should be pulled high.

Comment: When not connected, it is floating

Answer (score 2):

Not everything gets cleared on a reset, only the specified bits in the specified registers get set to the initial values given in the data sheet.

You can detect what kind of reset just happened (power on, external, watchdog, etc) by checking the reset flag bits in the MCUCSR register at the very start of your program. Pulling the RESET pin low will generate an "external" reset, so the EXTRF flag will be set when your code starts executing after the RESET pin is released.